# Groovy SQL - Storing the results of one query in a list to be iterated over in another query

Tags: mysql, groovy

I am currently trying to piece together a way of getting the results from one mysql query, adding them to a list, then iterating through these results in another query using Groovy.
My code is as follows:

```
String query = 'SELECT * FROM fields WHERE name = "ticket_status"';
def queryResults = []
Db.eachRow(query) {
    queryResults << it
}

def statuses = it.queryResults

String query2 = "SELECT count(*) FROM ticket WHERE name = ${statuses.join(',')};"
```

I am a bit unsure where to go from here, this does not appear to work, I'm unsure about the `${statuses.join(',')}`, I need to fill this specific bit of the query with each of the results of the previous query in turn.
I also need the list items to appear with quotation marks around them in order for the second query to work, which I am not sure can happen like this.
Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables.  It does not make sense to do `SELECT *` if you want only one column.  The entire problem can probably be reduced to a single `SELECT` with a `JOIN` between the two tables, but I can't figure out what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to do something like this I believe:

```
String query2 = "SELECT count(*) FROM ticket WHERE name IN ( '${statuses.join("','")}' );".toString()
```